# using pipeline for bulk processing in redis (python example)

Tags: python, redis, pipeline

I'm trying to clear my concept of pipelining implemented in redis, using a python client. Take the following example:

```
my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
for obj_id in list_of_obj_ids:
    hash_name="n:"+str(obj_id)
    sorted_set = "s:"+str(obj_id)
    if my_server.exists(hash_name):
        my_server.hset(hash_name,'val',0)
    if my_server.zcard(sorted_set):
        my_server.zadd(sorted_set, hash_name, time.time())
```

I.e. I'm updating multiple hashes via iterating through a for loop. How can I accomplish this kind of bulk update via pipelining? From what I've read, the following is what comes to my mind:

```
my_server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=POOL)
p = my_server.pipeline()
for obj_id in list_of_obj_ids:
    hash_name="n:"+str(obj_id)
    sorted_set="s:"+str(obj_id)
    if p.exists(hash_name):
        p.hset(hash_name,'val',0)
    if p.zcard(sorted_set):
        p.zadd(sorted_set, hash_name, time.time())
p.execute()
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about what [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) is/does and then you'll understand why this won't work - until you `execute` the pipeline, none of the commands in it will be sent to the server. That makes your conditional statements miss the purpose you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for helping Itamar. I've read that section (that's how I got introduced to redis pipeline). But I'm still unclear about how to `execute`. In my example, I call the `execute` method on `p` outside the for loop. That made sense in my head because I thought this way all commands will be executed in bulk once the for loop is done.

Comment: Exactly, which means that the calls the `exists` and `zcard` will only happen upon execution and not in the loop

Comment: I see. In which case, I ought to move `p.execute()` inside the for loop (at the end). But doesn't that place the `execute()` method within the loop, thus invoking it multiple times? OR, did you mean that having `p.execute()` outside the for loop was a correct approach in my example?

Comment: You'll need to execute outside, but you can't use the pipeline for commands that you use the replies of - these have to be executed outside that pipeline (but possibly in a pipeline of themselves ;)

Comment: By any chance, do you happen to know about the nuances of `zadd` time complexity? If so, would be great to get your observation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40870081/time-complexity-of-zadd-when-value-has-score-greater-than-highest-score-present