# Time complexity of zadd when value has score greater than highest score present in the targeted sorted set

Tags: redis, time-complexity

If every value one adds to a sorted set (redis) is one with the highest score, will the time complexity be `O(log(N))` for each `zadd`?

OR, for such edge cases, redis performs optimizations (e.g. an exception that in such cases where `score` is higher than the highest `score` in the set, simply add the value at the highest spot)?

Practically, I ask because I keep a global sorted set in my app where values are `zadded` with time since epoch as the score. And I'm wondering whether this will still be `O(log(N))`, or would it be faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a Sorted Set has grown over the thresholds set by the `zset-max-ziplist-*` configuration directives, it is encoded as a [skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Optimizing insertion for this edge case seems impossible due to the need to maintain the skip list's upper levels. A cursory review of the [source code](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/t_zset.c#L132) shows that, as expected, this isn't handled in any special way.